# Почему 1010 PHP

Tags: php

Почему выводит 1010?

```
<?php

class A{
    public $c = 5;

    public function a(){
        echo $this->c;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public $c = 10;

    public function b(){
        echo $this->c.$this->a();
    }
}

$obj = new a();
$obj->a();
?>
```

Comment: У меня выводит 55: http://ideone.com/VHX9Fu

Comment: __construct выполняет a()

Comment: для 1010 надо сказать `$b = new b();`

Comment: Ошибочка действительно $b = new b(); $b->a();

Answer (score 3):

В php4, чтобы задать конструктор нужно было создать метод, совпадающий с именем класса

```
class MyClass {
    function MyClass(){}
}
```

Эта конструкция была сохранена в php5 для обратной совместимости.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php

> В целях обратной совместимости, если PHP 5 не может обнаружить
>   объявленный метод __construct() и этот метод не наследуется от
>   родительских классов, то **вызов конструктора произойдет по устаревшей
>   схеме, через обращение к методу, имя которого соответствует имени
>   класса**. Может возникнуть только одна проблема совместимости старого
>   кода, если в нём присутствуют классы с методами __construct(),
>   использующиеся для других целей.
>
> В отличие от других методов, PHP не будет генерировать ошибку уровня
>   E_STRICT, если __construct() будет перекрыт методом с другими
>   параметрами, отличными от тех, которые находятся в родительском
>   __construct().
>
> Начиная с версии PHP 5.3.3, методы с именами, совпадающими с последним
>   элементом имени класса, находящимся в пространстве имен, больше не
>   будут считаться конструкторами. Это изменение не влияет на классы, не
>   находящиеся в пространстве имен.

Comment: А по поводу регистронезависимости, чтоб не повторятся http://www.askdev.ru/php/9201/%D0%9E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-PHP/